# Setting DOM element attribute while iterating over NodeList cause performance overhead

Tags: java, xml, dom, nodelist

I am having performance problem when I modify DOM element attributes while I am iterating over NodeList.

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
public static void overwriteSumDef(Document doc){
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("Session");
    int length = nl.getLength();

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        Element elem = (Element)nl.item(i);
        elem.setAttribute("sum-def", "MON-SUN");
        //elem.removeAttribute("sum-def");
    }
}
```

I have downloaded Apache Xerces2 Java code and tried debugging the internal implementation.
It seems like the elem.setAttribute() will set a flag in Document indicating that this document has changed then in the next time I try to get the next matched element, NodeList will clear the current list of matched elements and start searching from the root node all over again (correct me if I am wrong about this). Since the root node here is the document node so it will cause a lot of overhead if there are thousands of elements before my target elements. My questions are :

1. Is this inevitable since the NodeList need to be "live" according to DOM spec? or there is other implementations that handle this more efficiently?
2. If I replace the line of setting attribute with elem.removeAttribute("sum-def") then the flag will not be set. Why is removing attribute not considered as an operation that change DOM document?

Answer (score 0):

If that's what's really happening then you can build a list (e.g. ArrayList) of all the nodes that match by iterating over the NodeList and storing the elements in the ArrayList as you encounter them.  Then once you have all the elements in the ArrayList, iterate back through the ArrayList making your edits.